# uninstall ubuntu 8.10 and grub

Tags: uninstall

how do I remove ubuntu and grub from my vista system and regain access to my second hard disk where ubuntu is installed. There doesn't appear to be an uninstall option on the install disk, so I tried the install disk again. What resulted was 2 installations and about 6 partitions on my second hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

You **CANNOT** uninstall an os, the only option you have is to format its partition and overwrite its bootloader with another one.

In your case it seems like that you have two ubuntu installations on different drives and a vista installation too? and you now want to remove one ubuntu installation.

IMO, you should start your computer in ubuntu you want to use, open 'gparted', delete the drive of ubuntu that you **DO NOT** want to use and format it to some  other usable partition. Then just run in a terminal,

first,

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda

and then,

> sudo update-grub

That will sort out grub entries for every os that you have in your system.